# is the function $f(x,y)=(x\sin(y),x\cos(y))$ on the given interval injective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider $f:(0,\infty)\times (0,3\pi )\to \mathbb{R}^2$, given by
$$f(x,y)=(x\sin(y),x\cos(y)).$$ Is $f$ injective? I have to find $(x,y)\in f:(0,\infty)\times (0,3\pi )$ such that $x\not= y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$. I tried some $(x,y)$ but I don't find the right one...

Comment: When do the sine and the cosine coincide?

Comment: What do you know about periodicity of sin and cos?

Comment: sin(y)=cos(y) if $y=\frac{\pi}{4}$ for example

Comment: i get it, thank you^^

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic. Compare $f(x,y)$ with $f(x,y+2\pi)$.

Comment: oh yes, thank you. for example $(1,\frac{\pi}{2}),(1,\frac{5\pi}{2})$ are ok..